# For what orders are there only abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

It's about that $A_5$ is the smallest non abelian Group.
The task is to determine for what orders < 60 there are only abelian groups.
My idea was to go through all those orders and use the main theorem about abelian groups. But.. There must be a more elegant solution right?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This isn't exactly easy (beyond the primes).  Also, $A_5$ is not the smallest nonabelian group.

Comment: Also, how would the "main theorem about abelian groups" tell  you there are no nonabelian groups of a given order?

Comment: A hint:  there is a nonabelian group of every even order except for 2 and 4.

Comment: @Randall why is there a non abelian group of every even order except 2 and 4?

Comment: @wondering1123  do you know of the dihedral groups?  If not, this is going to be a killer exercise.

Comment: Oh yes sorry... O. O dihedral groups are of oder 2n.

Comment: For orders $\le 4$ and for prime orders, there are only abelian groups. For even $n>4$, see the other comments. Show that there are only $Z_9$ and $Z_3^2$ of order $9$. A standard beginner's exercise is to show that every group of order $15$ is cyclic (hence abelian). Up to $n=143$, check the zero entries in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups#List_of_small_non-abelian_groups

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A060652 for more info

Comment: $S_3$ is a non-abelian group.  $A_5$ is the smallest "non-solvable" group.  All groups $A_n, n\ge 5$ are non-solvable.  Then there is an odd-ball of order 168.